# How to echo large text variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string variable that is pulled from a database and manipulated before being echoed. I am receiving an "Out of memory" error and I suspect it is because some instances are large like 500 characters. I can always increase the memory limit but I'd prefer not to do that in this case as this is on a common page on my site and I want o avoid taxing the memory on my server. I've seen two other threads here on Stackoverflow but they aren't closely related; one recommended the heredoc syntax which I'm not familiar with; if that is an appropriate approach can someone explain that to me? Other ideas?

Comment: Go back and accept some answers to your previous questions and we'll talk.

Comment: @tubaguy50035, Way to represent us tuba players.  Gedalya is new, and could use some pointers, not drive-by criticism.  Gedalya, StackOverflow is a bit different than most forum sites.  It is recommended that you go back to some of the other questions you've asked and click the accept check-mark next to the answer.  This makes it easy for folks coming by later on to see what the answers were.  See the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @sudowned, ... and complaining about it with no recommendation for fixing is pointless.  If it actually bothered you, a suggestion for how to fix the problem is needed.  Otherwise, you are not helping the situation.

Comment: 500 characters shouldn't cause an out of memory error. Could you add some code so we can see what else might be causing the issue?

Comment: @Brad I disagree, the problem isn't complicated and the recommendation is implicit. You will note that I did in fact suggest how to fix the problem - it's comment number two - so perhaps you should consider how you yourself are representing tuba players. :p

Comment: @sudowned, You will note that my original note was pointed at tubaguy50035's initial comment, not yours.  He fixed his comment, now there is no issue.  Case closed.

Comment: Hi guys; thanks for the feedback. I've just answered two outstanding questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can hold strings up to 2 GiB and a script is by default set to a memory limit of 1 GiB. 500 characters (~500-2000 B) should be no problem at all. Please provide us with some more information and code :)

Comment: This was a problem on my part.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need some code to see what is wrong here. 500 characters won't ever cause an out of memory error (unless memory_limit is set to < 1MB or so).

There must be something else (like a loop) that causes this problem, but without code, we can't help you out I guess